# Foreman export upstart resetting $PATH

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, unicorn, foreman, upstart

Here is what I am running:

```
rbenv sudo foreman export upstart /etc/init -a myapp -p 8080 -u myuser
```

What gets generated in `...web-1.conf`

```
start on starting myapp-web
stop on stopping myapp-web
respawn 

exec su - myuser -c 'cd /home/myuser/apps/myapp; export PORT=8080; bundle exec unicorn -p $PORT -c ./config/unicorn.rb >> /var/log/myapp/web-1.log 2>&1'
```

When I run `tail -f /var/log/myapp/web-1.log`, I see the following:

```
-su: bundle: command not found
```

It appears $PATH is being reset. If I manually `cd` into that directory, while running under `myuser`, I can execute the command just fine. Thoughts?

I am using `foreman`, `rbenv`, `rbenv-sudo`, `unicorn`, `rails 4.0.0`, and `ruby 2.0.0-p247`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I had my `rbenv` being configured in `~/.bashrc`.

`su - myuser -c` is a login shell, but not an interactive shell.

I moved `rbenv` config to `~/.profile` and everything seems to be working now.

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, it helped me!